# leading zeros in mysql zerofill int field not showing when queried

Tags: mysql, zerofill

I have a table with auto increment zerofill ID numbers. When I query the data the IDs lose their leading zeros (i.e. "000529" returns as "529"). Is there a way to preserve the leading zeros, or even generate them back in the query statement? I know I can generate them back in PHP using STRPAD, but for the specific project I am on I would like to retrieve the data as it is in the DB.

Comment: It's probably PHP that casts these ID's to integers.

Comment: They are preserved here, so you'll need to give more information about how you connect, query, and possibly cast (make sure you get back strings, not integers). `mysql` & `PDO` will preserve them in a quick test here 'out of the box'.

Comment: SELECT id, name title, 'profile' type, date FROM intake WHERE name LIKE '%mi%' 
UNION ALL SELECT id, casename, 'matter' type, date_opened date FROM s_matters WHERE casename LIKE '%mi%' 
UNION ALL SELECT cid AS id, name title, 'call' type, date FROM s_calls WHERE name LIKE '%mi%' 
UNION ALL SELECT id, subject title, 'event' type, start_date date FROM s_events WHERE subject LIKE '%mi%'
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: the id fields and cid fields are 6-8 digits with leading zeros, but when the result is returned from that query, there are no leading zeros in any of the ids

Comment: Which MySQL library are you using? mysql_*(), mysqli_*() or the PDO class?

Comment: In mysql, do you use the `Int` type, `char` type or `Varchar` type as data type in the database, have you also confirmed that the leading zeros persist in the database

Answer (score 8):

Use function LPAD() to show the numbers (left) padded with zeros:

```
SELECT LPAD( 529, 6, '0') AS padded;
```

Comment: Or try : SELECT CONVERT(field, CHAR)

Answer (score 0):

It's the UNION ALL part that is converting them to INT - I've yet to find a simple solution. To my mind it's a mySql bug.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the field with leading zeros and use a UNION it will remove the leading zeros.
I found a workaround by adding:

```
CONVERT(id_number,char) as id_number
```

Obviously, `id_number` represents whatever zero filled field you are trying to SELECT.